# How to move a google map,after you have drawn a circle on it?

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm building an android app. I'm using Google Maps. When i set    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true) in the map is displayed a circle with certain radus. How can i move map, without moving that circle. Is there any solution?
Hope that someone helps me.
Thank you!

Comment: you mean the circle that shows you where your location is?

Comment: yes, at first it shows my current location,but after i want to move the map but not the circle. i want to use this, for counting how many markers are placed in a circle,somewhere in a map.

Comment: But if it shows your location, how can it move when you move the map? Doesn't make sense.

Comment: the "circle" moves when your location changes, not when the map moves

Comment: thank you, i want to ask something else if possible. if i draw a circle can i realize this?